# Consume ES6 Module that reads from package.json, inside of webpack config

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, commonjs

Very confusing, but let me try to explain.

I want to read the name field from package.json into an ES6 Module with a `default` export, for use inside of JSX.

```
const pkg = require('../../package.json');
const cssPrefix = `${pkg.name.split('/')[1]}__`;
export default cssPrefix
```

I also want to use that same name property, but in [Webpack 2](https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7#mixing-es6-with-amd-and-commonjs) webpack.config.js files *themselves*, ES6 module syntax still isn't supported.

The ways that work are kind of gross.

1. Use the compiled babel output directly (ES5), then `require('cssPrefix').default`.
2. Webpack JSON-loader, which is finicky at best right now.
3. Duplication of the name property to more than one location.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Why don't you just do `module.exports = cssPrefix;` ? Seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: And then `const cssPrefix = require('path/to/cssPrefix')?`

Comment: yep............

Comment: I've found you can also import it like so: `import cssPrefix from '/path/to/cssPrefix'`. Want to add your comment as an answer so I can upvote?

Comment: Actually, this throws an error in Webpack 2.1.0-beta25, but if I use json-loader, it fails silently.